# Not able to change dir in virtualenv django

Tags: django, bash, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have setup a virtualenv and installed django.
First I activated the virtualenv. so i was in /bin
then I wanted to run manage.py which is in /bin/movies
when I run cd /movies it says no directory found.
although the directory is present.
please help

Comment: Can we get more detailed information on your directory structure?

Comment: I got it bro. i used 'cd /movies' which as pointed by @Daniel was wrong Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a slash at the start, which means start from the root. Don't do that.

```
cd movies
```